# Looks like shared_ptr hides the error with lack of virtual destructor. Is that correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, virtual-destructor

Looks like shared_ptr hides the lack of virtual destructor in base class.

For this code:

```
class IInt {
public:
    /*virtual*/ ~IInt() {} // Lack of virtual destructor!
    virtual int get() const = 0;
};

class Int : public IInt {
public:
    Int(int a) : a(a) {}
    ~Int() { cout << "~Int:" << a << endl; }
    int get() const override { return a; }
private:    
    int a;
};
```

### shared_ptr - virtual destructor not needed

At the end of this block - `shared_ptr<IInt>` properly destructs the c101 - quite surprisingly the lack of virtual destructor in `IInt` is not a problem here:

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<IInt> c101 = std::make_shared<Int>(101);
    std::shared_ptr<IInt> c102(new Int(102));
    cout << c101->get() << endl;
    cout << c102->get() << endl;
}
```

Output:

> 101 
>   102 
>   ~Int:102
>   ~Int:101

### unique_ptr - virtual destructor needed

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<IInt> c103 = std::make_unique<Int>(103);
    std::unique_ptr<IInt> c104(new Int(104));
    cout << c103->get() << endl;
    cout << c104->get() << endl;
}
```

Output - **lack of proper destruction**:

> 103
>   104

### Question:

I am not asking for explanation how it happens it works that way. 
I hope I properly understand that all is the matter of destruction differences in `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`.

1. `shared_ptr` has destroying object attached to its control block - and this object once created is still there.
2. `unique_ptr` - destroying object is attached to every single unique pointer and its statically linked - and not change - cannot be taken from other pointer.

I am rather asking:

1. Is that somewhere documented? This difference in behavior? Any note in C++ standard saying that this can be confusing.
2. Are there any plans to change it?

Of course please correct and/or complete my short explanation if that is needed.

Comment: 1, Yes, in the standard. 2. No. This is "working as intended". And this isn't specific to `make_shared`. The following works, too: `shared_ptr<base> p = shared_ptr<Der>(new Der);`. The key is to get the correct deleter; once you have it, it stays.

Comment: As for the rationale, think of it this way: you are already paying the cost of type erasure in `shared_ptr`, which requires a dynamic dispatch. So instead of requiring *another* dynamic dispatch for the destructor, the two dispatches are "folded into one", if you will.

Comment: Y u no answer @KerrekSB ? =)

Comment: @PiotrNycz I don't think it's there explicitly. It's more of a consequence (albeit intended!) of the rules for deleters.

Comment: @PiotrNycz look at the copy ctor and `operator=`.  Both of them copy the source deletor.  Now look at how the deletor is defined during from-ptr and `make_shared` -- it is defined in terms of the object a shared pointer is referring to.  The result is that a shared pointer to base can use the deletor stored when the shared pointer to base was created.  Heck, you could use the "god mode" `shared_ptr<T>( shared_ptr<U>, T* )` ctor and create a view of a member of a class, and the dtor for the enclosing `U` will naturally be called.